# Indexing for SeqRecords

Tags: python, indexing, bioinformatics, biopython

I would like to get a list of indexes for SeqRecords that are in list f. I tried this:

```
for x in f:
    ind = f.index(x)
    print(ind)
```

But I get the error:

```
0
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\Sekwencje\skrypt 1.py", line 43, in <module>
  ind = f.index(x)

File "C:\Users\Adrian\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\SeqRecord.py", line 803, in __eq__
  raise NotImplementedError(_NO_SEQRECORD_COMPARISON)

NotImplementedError: SeqRecord comparison is deliberately not implemented. Explicitly compare the 
attributes of interest.
```

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example with your desired input and output? perhaps you mean `for ind, x in enumerate(f): print(ind)`-- unless by index you mean something else

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

You can't get the index of and SeqRecord in list, because **"SeqRecord comparison is deliberately not implemented"** (you got the explanation in error message - *NotImplementedError*). The `index()` method returns the lowest index in list that obj appears. But to do it, it needs a specific comparsion method, that is not implemented in Seq module.

### Hard method

Since python is a dynamic language, you can add a comparsion method to class. Even the error message is giving you the answer (*Explicitly compare the
attributes of interest*). Here is a code:

```
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

def equal_seqs(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, SeqRecord):
        raise NotImplementedError('Comparsion on wrong types!')
    else:
        return self.seq == other.seq # You can change it to whatever you want.

SeqRecord.__eq__ = equal_seqs

foo = SeqRecord('ATGCGCAT')
bar = SeqRecord('GACGATCA')

print(foo == bar)
# False

l = [foo, bar]
print(l.index(bar))
# 1
```

### Other possibility

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but if you wanted to print ID of a sequence, then you can do it as following:

```
for seq in sequences:
    print(f'{seq.id} {seq.name}')
```

Is that what you wanted?

### More info

If you want to read more info about rich comparsion methods, then you can find it **[here](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html)**